# Extract table from unstructured text file in r

Tags: r, regex, string, tm

I have a text file namely **data.txt** containing multiple tables in the following format.

```
//
// TABLE ET_ARCMAT
// ARCID                  MATID                                    VALTO      VALFR      MINLO                  MAXLO                  MAXFL  TRVOL                  TCONA                  TCONB                  TCONC                  TCOST                  SUBCO  TPRIO                  HORTO      RECTI
// STRING                 STRING                                   INT        INT        REAL                   REAL                   STRING REAL                   REAL                   REAL                   REAL                   REAL                   STRING REAL                   INT        INT
   01KNkQkk7jAziGNzdcbHDW 051MjWuW7jkNeBn4hOHngG                   738487     738068     0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E-02  o      0.000000000000000E+00  0          0
   01KNkQkk7jAziGNzdcbHDW Ww7Em5Fm7jk1dsFo2QZ130                   738487     738068     0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E-02  o      0.000000000000000E+00  0          0
   01KNkQkk7jES}VQys4BYhm Ww7Em5Fm7jk1dsFo2QZ130                   738487     738068     0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E-02  o      0.000000000000000E+00  0          0
   01KNkQkk7jES}WTyY4T2hm 051MjWuW7jkNeBn4hOHngG                   738487     738068     0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  1.000000000000000E-02  o      0.000000000000000E+00  0          0

// TABLE ET_ARC
// ARCID                  FLEID                  LOCFR                  LOCTO                  TTYPE                  DURAT      RNDTR                  TCTYP                  DISCR  RLDUR
// STRING                 STRING                 STRING                 STRING                 STRING                 INT        REAL                   REAL                   STRING REAL
   01KNkQfB7jA{yV0dDRB2r0 01KNkQfB7jA{yV0dDRB2r0 01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kGH7W 01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kEn7W 0003                   0          1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00
   01KNkQfB7kE5kmrh1M5ImW 01KNkQfB7kE5kmrh1M5ImW 01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kGH7W 01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kFn7W 0003                   0          1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00
   01KNkQkk7jAIb2l2O8wQ2G 01KNkQkk7jAIb2l2O8wQ2G ULkf}cY{L4Y{P1HCP6yexG avYtOUGQB4MYMCUioDjT9W 0003                   0          1.000000000000000E+00  0.000000000000000E+00  o      0.000000000000000E+00

//
// TABLE ET_DEMCLTIM
// DEMCL      LOCID                  MATID                                    BCKTO      LAPEN                  MAXLA      NDPEN                  PENGR
// INT        STRING                 STRING                                   INT        REAL                   INT        REAL                   INT
   1          01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kEn7W 051Meqlv7jgqwRJvGAyX1m                   69         4.500000000000000E+08  21         9.999999999000000E+09  0
   2          01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kEn7W 051Meqlv7jgqwRJvGAyX1m                   69         4.500000000000000E+08  21         9.999999999000000E+09  0
   3          01KNkQUr7jAkokBn7kEn7W 051Meqlv7jgqwRJvGAyX1m                   69         4.500000000000000E+08  21         9.999999999000000E+09  0
```

I need to extract all the tables and store them in an excel file. I've tried to search the code but could not find the correct code. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code which works well for me on the sample shared.

```
#read the data line wise
tmp <- readLines('data.txt')
#Get the position of table names
table_name_index <- grep('TABLE', tmp)
#Get the name of the tab;e
table_names <- sub('.*TABLE\\s+', '', tmp[table_name_index])
#Drop datatypes STRING, INT etc and the tablename
tmp1 <- tmp[-c(table_name_index + 2, table_name_index)]
#Drop empty rows
tmp1 <- tmp1[!(tmp1 == "//" | tmp1 == "")]
#split each table separately
setNames(by(tmp1, cumsum(grepl('//', tmp1)), function(x) {
  #Remove '//' from the column names lines
  x[1] <- sub('//\\s+', '', x[1])
  #Read the data as dataframe
  read.table(text = paste0(x, collapse = '\n'), header = TRUE)
}), table_names) -> list_of_tables

#Write to excel
writexl::write_xlsx(list_of_tables, 'result.xlsx')
```

The data is stored in excel with 3 separate sheets.

[image]